# Calling rchisq with vector parameters

Tags: r

What happens when I call `rchisq(100,1:100,1:100)`:

- does R generate 100 numbers with df=1,ncp=1?
- or does it generate 100 numbers each with df=k,ncp=k for  k=1...100?

What I want to know is whether  df and ncp can be vectors or not. It is not clear in the documentation (when compared with rnorm). I suspect that they can also be vectors and recycling happens if the lengths differ(?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just test it by using `set.seed()`:

```
R> set.seed(42); rchisq(2, 1:2, 1:2)              # base case
[1] 8.676 1.653
R> set.seed(42); rchisq(1, 1, 1); rchisq(1, 2, 2) # matches
[1] 8.676
[1] 1.653
R> set.seed(42); rchisq(1, 1, 1); rchisq(1, 1, 1) # does not match
[1] 8.676
[1] 0.5874
```

so it looks like you get N draws using degrees of freedom and non-centrality from the corresponding value in the supplied vector.

Viewed another way, recycling as actually the rules as scalar values for `df` and `ncp` get recycled to vector length which makes some sense.

Comment: I tried 'rchisq(10,1,rep(c(1,100),each=5))', confirms the answer. THX. General comment: I think that the R documentation is not really up to date when compared with MATLAB for example...

Comment: Easy. Just donate the few thousand dollars you save each time and the  R Foundation can probably be persuaded to hire some help for editing.  Kidding aside, the documentation is actually rather amazingly complete and if you make a convincing case on r-devel concerning a particular issue then _you_ can actually help to make it better.  Deal?

Comment: That's not how R source code works, but wiki.R-Project.org is eagerly awaiting other contributions :)